# MySQL creationg table error with Positional message

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Hello I am new to MySQL and having trouble creating a table. It says that the types im using are not valid at their position with ')'.

Can someone tell me what is wrong with this code snippet?

```
create table CUSTOMER(
    CustomerID int AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    LastName varchar, 
    FirstName varchar, 
    Address varchar, 
    City varchar, 
    State varchar, 
    ZIP number, 
    Phone number,
    EmailAddress varchar,
    constraint pk_cID primary key(CustomerID));
```

Comment: `VARCHAR` requires a size, e.g. `VARCHAR(100)` means up to 100 characters.

Comment: When I tried this, it said the error was at `, FirstName`, not `)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table should look like:

```
create table CUSTOMER(
    CustomerID int not null  AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    LastName varchar(100), 
    FirstName varchar(100),
    Address varchar(100),
    City varchar(100),
    State varchar(100),
    ZIP int, 
    Phone varchar(50),
    EmailAddress varchar(100),
    primary key(CustomerID)
);
```

- `number` is not a datatype in `MySQL`
- When you assign `auto_increment` it should be `not null auto_increment`
- You don't need a constraint for primary key, just add primary key.
- I don't  think the best way of storing Phone  numbers is `int`, you might have different formatting the best way is to treat numbers as addresses , so `varchar` would be better